# Projecting a path to form a curved 3d side wall in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I'm reviewing this [3d pie chart inkscape tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wWilRqEmfc&lc=z23zx3vzrkjoxxi5w04t1aokgffhqtyosctdckwznwk5bk0h00410.1551719157420968) and was curious whether there is a way to project the side walls using something like an extrude effect?  Here's a demo that creates two surfaces and then uses the [extrude extension to generate the side walls.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNn2yBV8CfA).  Is there something like this for curved surfaces?

[image]

Comment: Please post some images demonstrating what you are trying to achieve. I don't mind answering questions about Inkscape, but I'm not watching videos to find what you are talking about. Thanks.

Comment: I create at "Current point int time" URL for the youtube, so a simple click should be all that's necessary (No need to watch the whole thing).  I agree though that it's nice to have a full view right in this post.

Comment: The link points to part of a tutorial showing an envelope deformation. I don't see what that has to do with your question. I am going to ask you again. Forget videos, please post images showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: The first link posts the pie chart - the second link posts an example of the type of effect  / technique that I'm hoping exist which could speed up adding the side wall to the pie chart.  Right now the video author creates a shape and manually adjusts it so that it forms the vertical curved side wall of the 3d pie chart.  The extrude effect creates a side wall between two parallel surface ... I'm hoping that there is a technique / extension that automates this.

Comment: The purple wall between the top and bottom of the 3d pie chart surfaces is the part that wish there was a way to automatically generate.

Comment: @Ole well it would be quite trivial to make one.

Comment: @joojaa I agree - it is very easy to do "Humanly" - But it would be very cool if there was an extension that could generate a perfect fit based on parameters.

Comment: Perhaps an AI approach to guessing and generating the shape ...

Comment: @Ole its no more harder to program, than doing by hand.

Comment: @joojaa are you saying that there's an implementation coming?

Comment: @Ole could be if i used inkscape but i dont. Implementing this is not a big deal. Takes about an hour to be passable and a hour more to implement sorting (yeah i have done this in postscript and illustrator javascript ). Doing it yourself shouldnt be hard since you allready know what the algorithm is. In a ideal word that would mean you could write it as code.

Comment: Indeed it seems very doable.  I'm hoping Inkscape transfers the platform to Electron so that making extensions like this becomes even more trivial: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/rewriting-inkscape-in-javascript-7e351738c37c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you expect a tool to make extrusions with a few clicks, you are NOT interested in "how to draw it" explanations like this:

[image]

1)....8) = blahblahblah

Inkscape has extension Extrude which a little helps to extrude polygons, but the coloring must done manually. There's no such functionality as Illustrator's 3D extrusion effect.

Inkscape's files can be extruded elsewhere, but getting the result back to Inkscape as 2D vector is tricky, so tricky that the usefulness  of whole thing is questionable. It can be easier to do the job in Inkscape or in a 3D program alone.

Inkscape can write DXFs. That format is known in many CAD programs, so trying it is natural, if one has a 3D CAD program. Unfortunately Inkscape prepares DXFs for certain cuttimg machine and using them in CAD programs creates unexpected results.Two programs simply refused to extrude a closed shape. My third program did it.The result was possible to import back to Inkscape as PDF. It was a wireframe like 7A in the unwanted image.

The 3D program which did steps 5,6 and 7A, was MoI3D. There was still left supplementing to full closed colorable faces (7B) and coloring (8).

OpenSCAD can get a drawing from Inkscape as native OpenSCAD file. There's a downloadable extension for this export. It's here: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2805184 I must admit that I didn't try it because I cannot use OpenSCAD's command line user interface.

TinkerCAD accepts SVGs but outputs nothing which is readable as vector in Inkscape.

**Conclusion:** Draw it or use other software to create the 3D shapes.